# Rearrange this list of dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have this list of dictionaries.

```
[{'value': '299021.000000', 'abbrev': 'AAA'},
 {'value': '299021.000000', 'abbrev': 'BBB'},
 {'value': '8.597310', 'abbrev': 'CCC'}]
```

I want to transform this list to look like this;

```
[{'AAA': '299021.000000'},
 {'BBB': '299021.000000'},
 {'CCC': '8.597310'}]
```

Any hints on how to get started?

I am using python 3.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) you can do the following:

```
data = [
    {'value': '299021.000000', 'abbrev': 'AAA'},
    {'value': '299021.000000', 'abbrev': 'BBB'},
    {'value': '8.597310', 'abbrev': 'CCC'}
]

data_2 = [{elem["abbrev"]: elem["value"]} for elem in data]

print(data_2)
# Output:
# [{'AAA': '299021.000000'}, {'BBB': '299021.000000'}, {'CCC': '8.597310'}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have tested and verified that the answer works.

Answer (score 0):

Using for loop;

```
original_list = [
                 {'value': '299021.000000', 'abbrev': 'AAA'},
                 {'value': '299021.000000', 'abbrev': 'BBB'},
                 {'value': '8.597310', 'abbrev': 'CCC'}
                ]

transformed_list = [ ]

for i in original_list:
   key = i['abbrev']
   value = i['value']
   single_dict = {}
   single_dict[key] = value
   transformed_list.append(single_dict)
```

I prefer the answer from Xukrao using list comprehension. Elegant, easy to read in one line.